# React TypeScript using FC and passing to a function with additional params, type error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When using React.FC how do you call a seperate function passing props and an additional parameter?

for example passing the ID and props to update Color ?

Calling:

```
onValueUpdated={updateColor({ color, onColorUpdated }, 'red')}
```

Function:

```
interface IProps {
  color: Color;
  onColorUpdated: (color: Color) => void;
}

const updateColor: FC<IProps> = (props, colorId: keyof Color
) => (value: any) => {
  props.onColorUpdated({
    ...props.color,
    [colorId]: value,
  });
};
```

Error:

Type '(props: PropsWithChildren, colorId: "red" | "green" | "blue") => (value: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'FC'.
  Type '(value: any) => void' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement': type, props, keyts(2322)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can extend your interface to allow passing untyped props

```
interface IProps {
  color: Color;
  onColorUpdated: (color: Color) => void;
  [key: string]: any
}
```

then

```
const updateColor: FC<IProps> = ({color, onColorUpdated, ...props}) => {
    console.log(props.colorId);
}
```

EDIT: you can also extend component props with `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div">` so that you can pass in what the (for example) `div` element accepts

```
interface IProps {
  color: Color;
  onColorUpdated: (color: Color) => void;
} & React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"div">;
```

Comment: I see, it’s either in props when using iProps or I have to specific the types specifically or additionally.